# Cocos2d for iOS: understanding z layers

Tags: background, cocos2d-iphone, layer

I have a GameScene with enemies and player sprites added at z:0. I add a background layer to GameScene at z:-1 and this works fine for the main background. The only thing is that I would like to display some clouds and for this they should be at z:1 respect to the player and enemies sprites.

My approach is to add the clouds at z:2 of the background layer, but this is not good enough because they still appear below the enemies and player sprites.

I would have thought that the z value (2) would have been added to the background layer z value (-1) resulting in an absolute (compared to the GameScene parent layer) z value of z:1, hence above the z:0 of enemies and player sprites.

Clearly I am wrong.

I then observed that when I add a sprite to a layer, the sprite that is added last will be shown on top of the previous sprites if in the same layer (e.g. adding enemies after player sprites will show enemies on top of player sprite). I imagine this is a convention to avoid odd graphical effects (overlay of two images mixing up colours). **Is this correct?**

Now, my only solution would be to have multiple background layers (one for the clouds and one for the actual background terrain), and add them at different z levels of the GameScene. Would this be correct? The downside of this is that I have to maintain to classes that are logically similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [sample chapter about how draw order works](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/files/cocos2d-essential-reference-sample/Influencing_the_Draw_Order.html) in cocos2d from the upcoming [Cocos2D Essential Reference](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/blog) (more about this soon, follow my blog).

Here's a short summary how draw order works:

- where nodes have the same parent: nodes are drawn from lowest to highest zOrder
- where nodes have the same parent and same zOrder: nodes are drawn in the order they were added as child
- nodes of different parents are drawn in the order their parent nodes are drawn

The most important thing to take away is that zOrder only affects child nodes of the same level. If you have two child nodes A and B in your scene, and A gets drawn first, then all child nodes of A are also drawn below node B.

Comment: thanks a lot! Fantastic, very useful references:). Can't wait to see the full version of the online definitive guide :).

Answer (score 1):

During drawing elements are drawn in order, equal to zOrder property, i mean, item with zOrder -3 will be drawn before item with zOrder -2, item with zOrder 1 will be drawn after item with zOrder 0 and so on. All zOrders are working inside one node, because all node's content is drawing in it's `draw` method. Check CCNode's `visit` method and you see it in the code.

So, you can create different layers to be able to add game objects with different "deepth" relatieve to your scene. For example, background layer, obstacles layer, layer for enemies and heroes, layer for bonuses, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Morion clearly answers your doubts about the `zPosition` of the `CCNode`s. However, I would also like to add an answer to your second question.

Having two background layers in the `GameScene` is correct, especially if the clouds and the terrain don't interact or share the same code. This will actually be better in terms of code separation and modularity, IMHO.

However, if you would like to make them into one class (because of some reason), then all you have to do is call:

```
// Don't call this in the init, since the parent is obviously nil there...
[[self parent] addChild:cloud z:kBackgroundLayerCloudsZ tag:kBackgroundLayerCloudsTag];
```

Notice, that we only call the parent to add the children, and we have predefined constants that will help us maintain the layers. If you, at a later stage, want to add an intermediate Background Layer, change the constants and add a new one for the new Layer.

I use this approach a lot, but TBH, I think in your case two classes would be better. The case that I use this approach in is when I **have** to separate the sprites into layers (for better maintainability, code separation, ... etc), and at the same time the sprites from different layers are interleaved (sometimes sprites from layer1 is above, and sometimes sprites from layer2 are above).